# What are my cards good for once they have rotated out of Standard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I'm a little upset, but I am realizing this is just part of MtG.  I spent some time last year putting together some nice decks and stocking up on quite a bit of the M13 cards.  And then work / life got in the way I didn't get to play as much as I thought.

Now, M13 has rotated out.  I can still use my RtoR and GC and I've already ordered a deck builder's set for M14 which should get here today.  I realize that I can still technically use M13 for casual gameplay, but not sure I want to continue investing time deck building with them.

Should I just sell them?  Do I gain anything by holding onto them?  Maybe just keeping the rare cards?

Comment: note: m14 contains some cards that were in m13. The m13 versions of those cards are still legal in the standard format.

Comment: It is a ton of fun to play vintage constructed. That is what my group plays and some of the decks with old and new cards mixed together are brutal and so much fun to watch.

Comment: Agreed, vintage allows for some stunning decks, and is far more fun

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on how your question is worded, I assume you are talking about standard.

I believe you're really asking a more general question, **"What are my cards good for once they have rotated out of Standard?"**

- They can still be played in alternate formats, such as Modern, Legacy, and Commander (and casual, as you've noted)
- Some cards may be reprinted in standard again in the future, in which case you can use your old printings instead of buying new ones
- From an investment standpoint, some cards may appreciate in value

I personally hang onto all of my old cards as my collection hasn't gotten too unwieldly in size yet. Whether or not your want to sell yours off is really just a personal decision about whether you think you'll be interested in different formats in the future.

If you don't want them anymore, you might also consider trading them for more current cards with players who do play other formats.

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.  I've modified my question to be more general, as you stated.  Thanks.

Comment: it costs more to get started in the older formats (Modern, Legacy are the most viable) but 9 times out of 10 your cards will be worth the same 6 months later, and often worth more than you paid for them (particularly in legacy, where many cards cannot be reprinted due to the reserve list). This makes the older formats actually cheaper in the long run.